# C# WPF Disable ListBoxItem Selection in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

I have a ListBox with each ListBoxItem inside containing a label and an image (placed inside border). When I clicked on the image inside ListBoxItem, the ListBoxItem was selected. Is there any possible way to avoid ListBoxItem being selected when clicked on the image (ListBoxItem is allowed to be selected when clicking on the area other than the image).

```
               <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SymbolList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSymbol}" Style="{StaticResource WishlistListBoxStyle}"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="200" Padding="0">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Content="{Binding}" Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"/>
                                <Border Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Visible" CornerRadius="5" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="0 0 5 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Image Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="../Icons/Cross.png"/>
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveSymbolCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" 
                                                                   CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <Border.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Border.Style>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

```
        <Style x:Key="WishlistListBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#282C2F"/>
            
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                    <Border x:Name="WishlistBorder" Style="{DynamicResource WishlistBorderContent}">
                                        <ContentPresenter />
                                    </Border>

                                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                                        <Style x:Key="WishlistBorderContent" TargetType="Border">
                                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 2"/>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#50D3D3D3"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="WishlistBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                                            <Setter TargetName="WishlistBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#63C5DA"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="WishlistBorder" Property="Background" Value="#50D3D3D3"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Try setting the image's `IsHitTestVisible` property to `False`.  That might be enough but if there is any element of the template (i.e. a background panel) that is hit detectable you might have more work to do.    You might also need to set the ItemContainerStyle to make whatever is containing your image also not hit test visible.  It will help you to decipher this if you look at the live visual tree

Comment: you can also catch the click on the image in the code behind